# How to sort the rows of a table dynamically based on data-sort attribute in tr tag when its value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a table and I want to sort the rows by the user,Each row contains one input, for enter a row number. Here rows are sorted by `data-sort` Attribute in `tr` and each input has a `rownum` attribute whose value is equal to the value of the tr `data-sort` attribute.There are 6 rows here. We want to take the input value of each row, and move that row there, and the values of the attributes are the same as the input.For example, if you enter 1 in the input of one of the rows, that row will be our first row.
The following code runs for the first time, but after moving one of the rows does not work anymore.When its value changes. where is my mistake?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pn9fkgy6/2/)

```js
 $('.m').on('change', function () {
        
        var Des = parseInt($(this).val());
        var RowNum = parseInt($(this).attr('rownum'));
       
        $('tr[data-sort="' + RowNum + '"]').attr('data-sort', -100);
        $('input[rownum="' + RowNum + '"]').attr('rownum', -100);
        if (Des > RowNum) {
            for (var i = RowNum + 1; i <= Des; i++) {
                var newVal = i - 1;
                $('tr[data-sort="' + i + '"]').attr('data-sort', newVal);
                $('input[rownum="' + i + '"]').attr('rownum', newVal);
            }
        }

        if (Des < RowNum) {
            for (var i = Des + 1; i <= (RowNum - 1); i++) {
                var newVal = i + 1;
                $('tr[data-sort="' + i + '"]').attr('data-sort', newVal);
                $('input[rownum="' + i + '"]').attr('rownum', newVal);
            }
        }
        $('tr[data-sort="-100"]').attr('data-sort', Des);
        $('input[rownum="-100"]').attr('rownum', Des);

        var divList = $("tr");
        divList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (parseInt($(a).data("sort")) - parseInt($(b).data("sort")))
        });
        

        $("tbody").html(divList);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h4>
inter value between 1-6
</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="1" data-sort="1">
            <td>One</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="1" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" data-sort="2">
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="2" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" data-sort="3">
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="3" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4" data-sort="4">
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="4" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" data-sort="5">
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="5" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" data-sort="6">
            <td>six</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="6" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here, and the fiddle you provided doesn't appear to do anything at all

Comment: `rownum` is not a valid attribute.  Consider using `data-rownum`.

Comment: It did not differ, it still works for the first input value, but then it does not work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you rebuild and replace html piece of code on which you have your listener, you have to rebind event listener to the new created elements with class "m". Something as below (not elegant,only here to show a working example - and you don't need all your test. You just need to assign input value to data-sort attribut and then reorder with sort function)

```js
$('.m').on('change', function (evt) {
 
     changeOrder(evt);
        
     })
     

function changeOrder(evt){
  $this=$(evt.currentTarget);
  var Des = parseInt($this.val());
  var RowNum = parseInt($this.attr('rownum'));

  $this.parent().parent().data("sort",Des)


  var divList = $("tbody").find("tr").sort(function (a, b) {
   return (parseInt($(a).data("sort")) - parseInt($(b).data("sort")))
  });

  $("tbody").html(divList);

  $('.m').on('change', function (evt) {
    changeOrder(evt);
  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h4>
inter value between 1-6
</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="1" data-sort="1">
            <td>One</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="1" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" data-sort="2">
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="2" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" data-sort="3">
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="3" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4" data-sort="4">
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="4" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" data-sort="5">
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="5" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" data-sort="6">
            <td>six</td>
            <td>
                <input rownum="6" class="m" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```